# Why before pseudo element doesn't get 100% container height?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to understand why a :before pseudo element doesn't take 100% of parent's height:

```
<div class="view-details"><a href="/retro-beauty-bar">VIEW DETAILS</a></div>
```

Here, `view-details` (height 19px) has a `before` pseudo with only `border-left` property. But the `before` takes only 12px height.
I can get it the height I desire by setting absolute position but I don't think it is a good solution, as I need to use `margin`.

```
.view-details:before {
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #cbcbcb;
}

.view-details {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `::before` by default is `display: inline;` and, as such, takes the height of text in that line.

Comment: @connexo if I put display: inline-block then it disappears. Even width: 100% doesn't work, it still has 0px height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working, it might be something else in your code:

```css
.view-details:before {
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #cbcbcb;
}

.view-details {
    display: inline-block;
    
    font-size:40pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-details"><a href="/retro-beauty-bar">VIEW DETAILS</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes maybe something is F-up in the chain... can't compete with your example. I used display: flex in view-details and it got the correct height, in my particular case.